# Merging two arrays of objects

Tags: javascript, arrays, object

I have a bit of a problem where I am struggling on for a pretty long time now. I have two arrays:

`var arr1 = [{"x":1,"y":1,"value":null},{"x":2,"y":1,"value":null},{"x":3,"y":1,"value":null},{"x":4,"y":1,"value":null},{"x":5,"y":1,"value":null},{"x":1,"y":2,"value":null},{"x":2,"y":2,"value":null},{"x":3,"y":2,"value":null},{"x":4,"y":2,"value":null},{"x":5,"y":2,"value":null},{"x":1,"y":3,"value":null},{"x":2,"y":3,"value":null},{"x":3,"y":3,"value":null},{"x":4,"y":3,"value":null},{"x":5,"y":3,"value":null},{"x":1,"y":4,"value":null},{"x":2,"y":4,"value":null},{"x":3,"y":4,"value":null},{"x":4,"y":4,"value":null},{"x":5,"y":4,"value":null},{"x":1,"y":5,"value":null},{"x":2,"y":5,"value":null},{"x":3,"y":5,"value":null},{"x":4,"y":5,"value":null},{"x":5,"y":5,"value":null}];`

`var arr2 = [{"x":1,"y":1,"value":13},{"x":1,"y":3,"value":3},{"x":2,"y":2,"value":146},{"x":2,"y":3,"value":44},{"x":2,"y":4,"value":42},{"x":2,"y":5,"value":5},{"x":3,"y":2,"value":14},{"x":3,"y":3,"value":57},{"x":3,"y":4,"value":23},{"x":3,"y":5,"value":15},{"x":4,"y":2,"value":1},{"x":4,"y":3,"value":4},{"x":4,"y":4,"value":8},{"x":4,"y":5,"value":1},{"x":5,"y":4,"value":1},{"x":5,"y":5,"value":8}]`;

Where `arr1` always contains 25 objects and `arr2` contains a variable number of objects, but they are always formatted the same.

How do I combine both arrays into one, where for example:

`{"x":1,"y":1,"value":null}` from arr1 will be `{"x":1,"y":1,"value":13}` as a result, but `{"x":2,"y":1,"value":null}` from arr1 will stay the same, since arr2 does not have this object.

After merging it would be most ideal to have an array of 25 objects, where the field `"value"` is filled from the objects out of arr2.

**EDIT**
Alright, since I am getting a lot of downvotes, you can find my code on [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Warforce/Z5Gmk/11/)

Any help is very much appreciated!

Comment: @Avery My code is a complete mess but here: http://jsfiddle.net/Warforce/Z5Gmk/10/ you can find it.

Comment: @Dropout: jQuery is primarily a DOM manipulation library. Mot a array manipulation one.

Comment: jQuery is an option, I tried using `jQuery.unique()` but without success.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can achieve this using [jQuery extend](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.extend/) if that's an option.

```
var extendedArray = $.extend({}, arr1, arr2);
```

The code above will create a new object for you which will contain what you requested. If you don't want a new object, then just use

```
$.extend(arr1, arr2);
```

See the docs mentioned above for more info (like deep extending, etc..).

Comment: I did not know about this function, thank you very much!